# Can this rectangle fit in an isosceles triangle with two known sides?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Could a rectangle, 120cm by 60cm, fit inside a triangle with two sides that are 203cm each? (Third side unknown)
Edit: (I'm not a math student. This is a problem I encountered in life and figured I'd use this opportunity to learn something new)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: **Hint**: given that two sides of the triangle are equal, what kind of triangle is it?

Comment: How about trying the right-angled triangle?

Comment: By 'fit inside', do you mean that it has to touch all three sides such as in @jmerry first image?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  Draw a picture.  There are two configurations that make sense.  The triangle is isosceles.  It may help to bisect the triangle to make two right triangles and try to fit half the rectangle in.  Let $x$ be the leg of the right triangle.  If $x$ is too short the triangle is not wide enough for the rectangle.  If $x$ is too long, the triangle is not tall enough.  Is there a happy medium?

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I will draw it up and see if it works.

Comment: I put together a scaled down version and it fits. YAY!

Comment: Could you point me in a good direction that I can use to learn how to do this theoretically?

Comment: The left hand version would fit with a side of $120 \sqrt 2 \approx 170$.  Half the base and the altitude need to be $120$

Answer (score 0):

Some more configurations worth looking at:

[image: Triangles]

Put two vertices on one of the length-203 sides, with one at or near the vertex between them. This comes out particularly simply if it's a right triangle at that vertex.

OK, the obtuse angle isn't going to be optimal - reducing the angle to $90^\circ$ will make things easier in that configuration. In the acute-angle range, there's a tradeoff, so it isn't obvious what angle is best just by looking.

Comment: Thanks! This might be a valid option for me as will.